# using a variable in sumifs in Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use sumif with a variable criterion. However, the criterion is embedded in a string in the range. Thus, I need to use the * sign to say that all rows that contains the value in  range "G5". In writing this formula I used '=*G5*', as the criterion. The formula is on range H4. the criterion is on G5. I want all rows that contains the value in G5

I could not make this work. I have 3 variables, the last row of the sum range, and the last row of the range and the criterion.

I will set the last row of the variable, in this case, the last row on column H and D is 76

```
Dim VH, VD as string

Dim ezy as string

VH="H76"
VD = "D76"
```

Ezy contains the equivalent of '*G5*', meaning any row that contains the value of G5 meets the criterion.

On column H5, I want to put a sumif formula that will add all amounts in column D, this the sum range

The criterion is on column G5. The range is from H7 to  VH, The sum range is from D7: to VD

On the criterion, I want to put an asterisk to add those rows containing the criteria. So, on G5, I can put a word that will be used as the criterion.

Supposing on G5, I put the word 'size14', I want to add on column D all amounts that has the word 'size14' on column H.

This is the formula that does not work

I  substitute the  variable Ezy to the concantenated '*G5*' , this means any row that contains the value of G5

```
Ezy = Chr(34) & "*" & G5 & "*" & Chr(34)
Sheets("Deposit).Select

 Range("H5").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUMIF(H7:" & VH & "," & Ezy & ",D7;" & VD & ")"
```

What  am I missing here?

Comment: Not to nitpick but [the singular of criteria is criterion](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/criterion)...

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Ezy = """*""&G5&""*"""
Sheets("Deposit").Range("H5").Formula = "=SUMIF(H7:" & VH & "," & Ezy & ",D7:" & VD & ")"
```

The cell formula needs to look like:

```
=SUMIF(H7:H76,"*"&G5&"*",D7:D76)
```

so you need to embed the additional double quotes, as well as include the literal text '&G5&'. You also had a semicolon rather than colon in the third argument, but that may have just been a typo.

Comment: You should probably try and provide a minimal explanation of what you did here and why it works for it to be a good answer.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with `SUMIF` yet it seems to work with `SUMIFS`. Also, this works only with text. If the search criteria is a number and partial numbers need to be searched then the "search range" needs to be converted to text first.

Comment: @Ralph It does work with SUMIF. Since wildcards only work with text in SUMIF(S) formulas, it would be no different in VBA.